# the code to change font names, size for textbox in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

try to find the code to change font names, size for textbox in Excel macro, all my codes from " .font.name= to End with" shows wrong in VBA, any suggestions? thanks

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)

  Set tx_ = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 382, 266, 122, 20)

tx_.TextFrame.Characters.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 8)

  With tx_.TextFrame.Characters.Text

  .Font.Name = "Tahoma"

  .Font.Size = 10

  .Font.Bold = msoTrue

  End With
```

Comment: Try using `.TextFrame.TextRange.` instead of just `.TextFrame.`. It would be helpfult ot know what error message you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas [`.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters.text) is a valid property of the [`.Characters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters) object, [`.Font`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters.font) is not a sub-property of it of some sort. It is a property to the object on it's own. Therefor the following worked for me:

```
Sub Tst()

Dim myDocument As Worksheet: Set myDocument = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim tx As Shape

Set tx = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 382, 266, 122, 20)
With tx.TextFrame.Characters
    .Text = mydocument.Cells(6, 8)
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Bold = msoTrue
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: works now, how to change the foreground color and background color?